# Using .hover selector mixing with up and down keys

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I have following CSS selectors that highlight the selected entry in a lookup list either using up and down keys or mouse pointer. Issue is when using both keyboard and mouse, multiple entries are getting highlighted. Following here is the CSS entries.

```
&:hover, &.selected {
                background: #205081;
                label {
                    .title {
                        color: #fff;
                    }
                    .subTitle {
                        color: #ccc
                    }
                }
            }
```

.selected CSS class is dynamically set based on up and down key events.Any suggestions on fixing this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is a browser's user specific setting and you wouldn't want change a user's setting as they generally have a reason for that. Especially when they are blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sibling selector is always tricky.
Given that your styles are applying to `ul`, `li`, you can take `:hover` prior to `.selected` using trick with parent's `:hover` like this:

```
@mixin high-light()
{
    background: #205081;
    label {
        .title {
            color: #fff;
        }
        .subTitle {
            color: #ccc
        }
    }
}
@mixin unhigh-light(){
    background: #fff;
    label {
        .title {
            color: #000;
        }
        .subTitle {
            color: #000
        }
    }
}
ul{
    &:hover{
        li{
            &.selected{
                @include unhigh-light();
            }
        }
    }
    li{
        &:hover, &.selected, &.selected:hover {
            @include high-light();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample of html markups:

```
        <ul>
            <li><label><span class="title">Item</span></label></li>
            <li class="selected">
                <label><span class="title">Item</span></label>
            </li>
            <li><label><span class="title">Item</span></label></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  After applying the following style still it highlights two entries one from the keyboard selection and other from the mouse hover.

Comment: Here is the html template <section repeat.for="item of items" class="${$index == selectedAutocompleteItemIndex ? 'selected' : ''} " >               
                 <label>
                      <span class="title">${item.title}</span><span class="subTitle">${item.subTitle}</span>
                 </label>
             </section>

Comment: @Faizal, I made assumption with `ul`, `li`. From your html template, you should change elements in scss to `parent element`, `section` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I also found out that Mouse Over event can be implemented at the section level and unhighlight selections by key press events.